# Modify form size at runtime while it's maximized

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, resize

I have to modify the size of my main form depending on which tab is selected. The below code is working except if the form window is maximized. It would be a solution to 'exit' that maximization first, and then modify the size. How to approach that?

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            this.Width = x;
            this.Height = y;
        }
        else if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            this.Width = x;
            this.Height = y;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like it would be a usability nightmare... after clicking on a tab page the window resize could move your mouse away from the tabs completely, which would just be jarring to say the least

Comment: I'm merging 3-4 tools into one winform app. Each of them has it's own size. I could re-arrange everything, but there are applications looking nice both normal size and maximized, but there are apps looks awful in full size. What option I have left?

Comment: 1. Make each app a separate window that loads from a main window (even have them docked inside the main window). 2. Base the size of the window off the largest tab's size. 3. If all else fails, ensure that the top left corner of the window stays in the same place. This would still be jarring, but not as bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set [Form.WindowState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) However I don't think that it is a good idea to undo maximization and change form size at runtime.

Comment: Because the user doesn't expect the window size to change when he selects a different tab. If you want control over the size of your form, don't allow the user to maximize it.

Comment: But some functions on some of my tabs requires maximization to be able to used them conveniently.

Comment: @fishmong3r because by clicking controls on form I don't expect that it will resize the form. Also if user jas set a form to be maximized - it should remain maximized until user will normalize it.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximised)
{
    WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
}

// Now you can change the size.
this.Width = x;
this.Height = y;
```